# Mix of SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR in one program?

Tags: c, multithreading, scheduling, fifo, round-robin

I want to create 3 threads with RR scheduling. In each of the threads I will create e.g. 5 threads with FIFO scheduling.

I know that 3 threads have a specified process time. In this period the other 5 threads should be run with "RR" scheduling.  After the period the other 2 threads should be start they work.

Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0):

you are talking about specified time .you should calculate the overall time in percentage like  20, 20, 40 % for the respective threads,to divide the cpu time in ratio .try to give pritiority to theses threads.and make the same ratio with priority as process time